# Protractor test failed in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

Test failed in chrome with error :Failed: No element found using. In Firefox works right.

```
describe("Main page functionality", () => {

var mainPage;
var url = "https://prom.ua/ua/";
var request = 'iphone';

beforeEach(() => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get(url);
    mainPage = require("../pages/mainPage.js");
});

it("Test search response title has requsted text", () => {
    var mainPage = require("../pages/mainPage.js");
    mainPage.search(request);
    expect(mainPage.getResponseTitle().getText()).toContain(request);
});
});
```

Comment: If the error comes from `mainPage.getResponseTitle()`, please show the this function code and code related to this function. Also show the error message includes information of using which locator failed to find element

Answer (score 0):

First check on which element fails and then you can add wait for the element to be visible:

```
 browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("id"))), 30000, "Element is not visible").
```